# Using php variables in ORDER BY statement gives error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The following is my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT date, status, reason 
        FROM tbl_attendance_mgmt ORDER BY date $order 
        LIMIT $number 
        WHERE fk_stu_id = '$stu_id'";
```

Here:

```
$order: ASC or DESC
$number: Number of rows to be displayed.
```

Can someone please help me out why this query gives me the error while executing it?

Comment: Which error do you receive?

Comment: I don't know what the error is but the error goes like: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"\n\n","status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}

Comment: In such case it would be useful to read PHP's log file or (if you aren't running in production) enable PHP to output useful error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your query this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT date, status, reason 
        FROM tbl_attendance_mgmt
        WHERE fk_stu_id = '{$stu_id}' 
        ORDER BY date $order 
        LIMIT $number ";
```

You have to bind your php variables using curly braces{}

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Even this query didn't work

Comment: try again, i just re-edit it

Comment: if you try that again and it still doesn''t work rap all your php variables wit { }

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: yeah, good to hear that

Answer (score 1):

You must have follow sequence for sql query. `WHERE` place before order by clause

```
$sql = "select `date`, status, reason from tbl_attendance_mgmt  where fk_stu_id = '$stu_id' order by `date` $order limit $number";
```

Comment: This still gives me error.

Comment: Nopes, still the same thing.

Comment: Which error are yo getting?

Comment: I don't know what the error is but the error goes like: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"\n\n","status":500,"statusTe‌​xt":"Internal Server Error"}

Comment: `echo $sql` and show your query

Comment: select `date`, status, reason from tbl_attendance_mgmt  where fk_stu_id = '3' order by `date` asc limit 10

Comment: your query looks fine. There may be error somewhere else

Comment: Maybe. Thanks for the concern anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT date, status, reason 
FROM tbl_attendance_mgmt
WHERE fk_stu_id = " . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $stu_id) . "
ORDER BY date $order 
LIMIT $number ";
```

1. You should escape your variables
2. A query should be in this order: `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, and `LIMIT`: